# How to replace and accumulate a "String" in a variable?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, replace

Assume that the HTML code below is inside an array of size 4.

Position 0:

```
<strong style="font-size:20px;">strong</strong>
```

Position 1:

```
<p style="color:rgb(255, 0, 0);">word 1<strong class="strong">strong</strong>word 2</p>
```

Position 2:

```
<div style="margin-left:244.4px;">
    <p class="pe">word 1<strong class="strong">strong</strong>word 2</p>
</div>
```

Position 3:

```
<div style="padding-top:10px;">
    <div class="div2">
        <p class="pe">word 1<strong class="strong">strong</strong>word 2</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

What's the best way to get the `String` below?

```
<div style="padding-top:10px;">
    <div style="margin-left:244.4px;">
        <p style="color:rgb(255, 0, 0);">word 1<strong style="font-size:20px;">strong</strong>word 2</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note that my intention is to remove all `class` and insert the `style` into their respective `TAGS`.

I had used two `for` repeating loops to iterate like an array, and I also used `replace()` to do the replacements. However, the code was too big and difficult to understand.

Comment: Let's see your for loops. Maybe it can be cleaned up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [posthtml](https://github.com/posthtml/posthtml) to parse the html into an AST so that you can get the tags of the first few elements. Then you can modify the last element and add the `style` attributes and remove the `class` attributes.

Link to repl: https://replit.com/@Programmerraj/stackoverflow-68136891#index.js

Code:

```
const parse = require('posthtml-parser').default
const posthtml = require('posthtml')

const arr = [
  `<strong style="font-size:20px;">strong</strong>`,
  `<p style="color:rgb(255, 0, 0);">word 1<strong class="strong">strong</strong>word 2</p>`,
  `<div style="margin-left:244.4px;">
    <p class="pe">word 1<strong class="strong">strong</strong>word 2</p>
</div>`,
  `<div style="padding-top:10px;">
    <div class="div2">
        <p class="pe">word 1<strong class="strong">strong</strong>word 2</p>
    </div>
</div>`
]

const asts = arr.slice(0, -1).map(str => parse(str))

const stylesByTag = new Map(asts.map(
  ([{ tag, attrs: { style }}]) => [tag, style]))

const { html } = posthtml()
  .use(tree => {
    tree.walk(elem => {
      if (typeof elem === 'string') return elem
      return {
        ...elem,
        attrs: {
          style: stylesByTag.get(elem.tag),
          ...Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(elem.attrs)
            .filter(([k]) => k !== 'class'))
        },
      }
    })
  })
  .process(arr[arr.length - 1], { sync: true })

console.log(html)
```